# Does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Does $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n}$ diverge?**

It is clear that the alternating Harmonic series converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\log 2.$$
Thus, $S_k=\displaystyle\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n}$ converges for each $k$. For each $k$, the sum could be expressed either as $\log 2-\alpha$ or $\alpha -\log 2$. So, we're really only interested in how much $S_k$ deviates $(\alpha)$ from the alternating series $S_1$. The numerators of $S_k$ follow [for even $k$](https://oeis.org/A049281) and [for odd $k$](https://oeis.org/A082687).

However, it seems that the partial sums may slowly go towards infinity [as shown in this Wolfram plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(sum%20(-1)%5E(n%2Bk)%2Fn%20from%20n%3Dk%20to%20infinity)%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity). Reasonably, since the difference between $S_1$ and $S_k$ probably behaves like $O(1/k)$, the sum probably diverges.

*What would be the best way to show convergence/divergence?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of the first two terms is
$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=1}1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\dots\\
&\phantom{=1-1}\frac12-\frac13+\frac14-\frac15+\frac16-\dots\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
The sum of the next two terms is
$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=\frac13}\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\dots\\
&\phantom{=\frac13-\frac13}\frac14-\frac15+\frac16-\dots\\
&\phantom{1}=\frac13
\end{align}
$$
The sum of the first $2n$ terms is
$$
H_{2n}-\frac12H_n\sim\frac12\log(n)+\log(2)+\frac12\gamma
$$
Thus, the series does diverge.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_k=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+k}}{n+k}.$ We have $$A_k=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}B(m,k)$$ where $B(m,k) =\frac {1}{2k+2m}-\frac {1}{2k+2m+1}.$

We have $B(m,k)>B(m+1,k)>0 $. So $$A_k>\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}B(m,k)\geq$$ $$\geq  kB(k-1,k)=$$ $$=k(\frac {1}{4k-2}-\frac {1}{4k-1})=$$ $$=\frac {k}{(4k-2)(4k-1)}>$$ $$>\frac {k}{(4k)(4k)}=\frac {1}{16k}.$$ So $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{16 k}=\infty.$

Note: $\frac {1}{16 k }$ is not meant to be an accurate estimate for $A_k.$ Just a useful lower bound.